# How do I reload the original webview

Tags: webview

If I send a push to a specific link in my webview app how do I create an action for people to hit "home" to reload my homepage so it sends them back to the page they would go to if they just opened the app.

Comment: you can enable javascript

Comment: Where does that go in all my files?

Comment: You want to go to default URL that opens up first or rather some activity or fragment?

Comment: Yes I want to have a home button that users can push on the bottom tool bar to take them to the homepage of my webview (website)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a button, then do something like:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            webview.loadUrl(PUT_HOME_PAGE_URL_HERE);

        }
    });
```

Or you can use WebView in a fragment, and change the fragments.